# Renderscript for blur animation VAR not recognized

Tags: java, android, bitmap, blur, renderscript

I'm trying to make a method for blurring a bitmap

Using the easy method with JAVA is too heavy on the CPU i guess, so i though of using renderscript

BUT here is my problem, the "var" in the method are not recognized

```
var cannot be resolved to a type
```

- Renderscript librady support V8 is imported
- Everything is recognized ok except "var"

Here is the method :

```
public Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap input, Context context) {
    var rsScript = RenderScript.create(context);
    var alloc = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(rsScript, input);
    var blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.Create(rsScript, alloc.Element);
    blur.SetRadius(12);
    blur.SetInput(alloc);
    var result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig());
    var outAlloc = Allocation.CreateFromBitmap(rsScript, result);
    blur.ForEach(outAlloc);
    outAlloc.CopyTo(result);
    rsScript.Destroy();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That code looks like an example from C#, uppercase first letter and the use of `var` to lazy type a variable. If that is an example from C#, the solution is to replace `var` with the correct type for each attribute.

Comment: yes you are right, i must be tired, i just changed all the values to the right types ...:/